# GotoXY is not working as i expected

Tags: c, console

GotoXY is not working if i separate the functions it will work but i need them all in the same file.

```
#include "colors.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#define clear() printf("\033[H\033[J")



void gotoXY(int x, int y) {
    COORD coord;
    coord.X = x;
    coord.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
}



void welcome() {
    printf("%s", KRED);
    printf("  _       __________    __________  __  _________\n");
    printf(" | |     / / ____/ /   / ____/ __ \\/  |/  / ____/\n");
    printf(" | | /| / / __/ / /   / /   / / / / /|_/ / __/   \n");
    printf(" | |/ |/ / /___/ /___/ /___/ /_/ / /  / / /___   \n");
    printf(" |__/|__/_____/_____/\\____/\\____/_/  /_/_____/   \n");
    printf("                                                 \n");
    printf("\n\n%s", KGRN);
    sleep(3);
    clear();  
}

void menu_main_interface() {
    clear();
    printf("%s",KBLU);
    printf(" ___  ___  ___  _____ _   _   ___  ___ _____ _   _ _   _ \n");
    printf(" |  \\/  | / _ \\|_   _| \\ | |  |  \\/  ||  ___| \\ | | | | |\n");
    printf(" | .  . |/ /_\\ \\ | | |  \\| |  | .  . || |__ |  \\| | | | |\n");
    printf(" | |\\/| ||  _  | | | | . ` |  | |\\/| ||  __|| . ` | | | |\n");
    printf(" | |  | || | | |_| |_| |\\  |  | |  | || |___| |\\  | |_| |\n");
    printf(" \\_|  |_/\\_| |_/\\___/\\_| \\_/  \\_|  |_/\\____/\\_| \\_/\\___/ \n");
    printf("%s",KGRN);                                                       
    printf("\n\n ________________________________________________________\n |");                                                       
    printf("                                                      |\n");                    
    printf(" |                     1 ---> NEW GAME                  |\n"); 
    printf(" |                     2 ---> LOAD GAME                 |\n");                                                
    printf(" |                     3 ---> TOP 10 TIMES              |\n");
    printf(" |                                                      |\n");
    printf(" |                     0 ---> EXIT                      |\n");
    printf(" | ENTER OPTION:                                        |\n");
    printf(" |______________________________________________________|\n");
    gotoXY(16, 25); 
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    printf("%s", KGRN);
    welcome();
    start();

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

And start() function only calls select_menu_interface() leading to:

```
void select_menu_interface() {
    int selection;

    do {
        menu_main_interface();
        readInt(&selection, 0, 3, "");
        switch (selection) {
            case 1: select_newgame(); break;
            case 2: break;
            case 3: readHS(); break;
            case 0: break;
            default: printf("ERROR: Bad Input!"); break;
        }
    } while (selection < 0 && selection > 3);

}
```

I want the cursor on "Enter Option:", but its doesn't work : the cursor is on the beginning of another line instead:

[image]

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a problem description.

Comment: Where is your `main` function ? Please read this: [mcve].

Comment: Please don't link to external resources for screenshots. You can upload a image here on SO.

Comment: @Steve I'm not sure that a new user without enough reputation can.  I've edited the question to achieve this

Comment: @Lundin in fact OP provided in a link the picture to show what doesn't work (i.e. the cursor is somewhere else)

Comment: @Christophe The lack of punctuation caused me to read that as "<link> This is the output I want...".

Comment: @ppfernandes can you please remove from your question the other display functions,  but show us instead how `menu_main_interface()` is called (and especially how you make your input afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution (credits to @Christophe):

The `readInt()` function does a `displayMessage()` that changed the cursor position.
We only needed to change it to a `scanf()` function to read the value:

```
void select_menu_interface() {
    int selection;

    do {
        menu_main_interface();
        scanf("%d", &selection);
        switch (selection) {
            case 1: select_newgame(); break;
            case 2: break;
            case 3: readHS(); break;
            case 0: break;
            default: printf("ERROR: Bad Input!"); break;
        }
    } while (selection < 0 && selection > 3);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, it appears that you're using [ANSI terminal escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to clear the screen and set the colors.  As the windows command console doesn't support these codes by default (ANSI.SYS is no longer available):

- either you're using an older windows version or a third party console emulator,
- or you set the [`ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING` flag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt638032(v=vs.85).aspx) using `SetConsoleMode()`.

In the first case, we couldn't help much.  But I have tested the second case : it appears that your position in `gotoXY()` does not match the screen layout that you show us:  the first argument is the column, and the second is the line.  So `gotoXY(16, 25)` would go to the line 25 (i.e. the 26th line on screen as the positions start with 0).  That would be at least 8 lines below your last line (assuming that your color sequences do not add lines).  For getting the right position I had to use `gotoXY(23,15);`

This confusion could explain scrolling (if line 25 is beyond the size of your windows in vertical limit).  But to get the cursor at the begin of the screen would require the horizontal position to go beyond the horizontal size of the windows (i.e. at least >57), which is not the case here.

So a couple of other possibilities to explore:

- as stdio is buffered,  it could be safe to do a `fflush(stdout)` before the cursor positioning, to ensure that the buffering is not causing some troubles (e.g. a trailing newline char to be displayed later, for example when you're using other I/O function such as reading the keyboard.
- check that  `readInt()` is not altering cursor position, for example, through a new line (I see a trailing "", so I suppose that the function could display something.